# How to get the output of at command in current or another terminal window

Tags: linux, io

I am trying to use the Linux `at` command, but it seems the only way I can get to see the output is by redirecting it to a file, like so:

```
# at now + 1 minute
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> date > afile.txt
at> <EOT>
```

This works as expected but is there a way to get the command (`date` in this example) to print the output on the terminal screen or open another one and output over there instead of a file?

I am basically trying to schedule things like syncing and building.

Comment: And if you close the terminal?  Should the `at` command still run?  There's a reason `at` detaches from the terminal.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/9
$ at now + 1 minute
at> date | tee /dev/pts/9
at> <EOT>
$ dim. juin  3 21:51:00 CEST 2012
```

Or to open a new terminal :

```
$ at now + 1 minute
at> DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xterm -hold -e 'date'
at> <EOT>
```

Or with `zenity` dialog boxes :

```
$ at now + 1 minute
at> DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/zenity --info --text "$(date)"
at> <EOT>
```

Comment: +1 Please correct typo in zenity command: `--test` should be `--text` (I cannot correct it myself due to the ['at least 6 characters'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters) rule.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `...  > afile.txt at>` use `> /dev/stdout 2> /dev/stderr`