# How to run a scrip if the time is matched with a time in another time zones

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Currently, I am using cloud VMs to run my code and because of that I am assigned with a new VM that is in a different time zone. I want to run a bash script that runs a python script at 7:30 pm (Eastern time). From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18945782/11748994) I know how to run a bash script at a specific time, e.g., `echo "ls -l" | at 07:00`. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26802324/11748994) I know how to get the current time of Eastern time, e.g., `TZ=America/New_York date`. Also, from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/335576/1089494) I know how to get only the time using `date +%R`.

I am a `Python` coder and tried my best to write a sudo code that shows what I am trying to accomplish as a bash script:

```
while true
do
Now=TZ=America/New_York date +%R
if [Now -eq 7:30pm] 
then
python3 myfile.py
done
```

Comment: How about `echo "python3 myfile.py" | at $(date -d "19:30 EST" +%R)`?

Comment: @tshiono: I get `warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh`, what is the meaning of `executing using /bin/sh`? Also,  what does `date -d` so here, especially flag `-d`? Finally, it looks like it was executed but it did not printed out `"python3 myfile.py"` in a terminal where I ran by bash file, how can I see the executed log?

Comment: The warning is a routine phrase of `at` command just telling the input commands are *not* executed under the user's favorite shell such as /bin/bash. There is no difference so far and you can ignore it. `date -d STRING` takes the provided STRING as a time instead of *now*. In my example above it converts `19:30 EST` to the local time. As for the output of `at` command, please take a look of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873417/how-to-get-the-output-of-at-command-in-current-or-another-terminal-window).

Comment: @tshiono: "are not executed under the user's favorite shell such as /bin/bash." but the warning says "will be executed using /bin/sh". I did not get it. Also, please post your solution as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Okay, I've posted my answer adding some explanations. Hope it explains better. BR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know how to set the `at` command to execute a command
at the specified time, and how to convert the EST to the local time,
you can just combine them:

```
echo "python3 myfile.py" | at $(date -d "19:30 EST" +%R)
```

When you invoke the `at` command, it always warns
"commands will be executed using /bin/sh". It will matter *only* if we invoke
a bash specific command such as:

```
echo "shopt -s globstar; ls **" | at ..
```

which will fail.

In our case, the command `python3 myfile.py` will run with both
`/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` then you do not worry about the warning.

`date -d STRING` interprets the `STRING` as a date/time representation
and prints the converted date/time in the specified format `+%R`.

If you want to send the output to a file, you can say:

```
echo "python3 myfile.py > /path/to/a/file" | at $(date -d "19:30 EST" +%R)
```

In order to output to the current terminal, first identify the terminal
with `tty` command:

```
$ tty
=> /dev/pts/0
```

Then redirect the output to the terminal with:

```
echo "python3 myfile.py > /dev/pts/0" | at $(date -d "19:30 EST" +%R)
```